# What is the frequency tolerance of AD9833 module?

Tags: arduino, frequency

I am making a frequency generator with the resolution of 0.1 Hz and I have found AD9833 module is what I need and had tried using it and it works! But not for all range. At some range I do get some deviation which is more than 0.1Hz. For example, I have tried at 619.3Hz and 707.8Hz (wow thats very specific ^^) and the actual frequency deviates to 619.19Hz and 707.63Hz respectively (both deviates more than 0.1Hz).

DOes anybody knows the frequency tolerance of the AD9833 module? Or the reason of my frequency deviation?

Comment: What does the data sheet say? What precision XTAL is being used?

Comment: Only the basic XTAL from the module:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/AD9833-Programmable-Microprocessors-Serial-Interface-Module-Sine-Square-Wave-DDS-Signal-Generator-Module/32837067609.html

Answer (score 1):

The AD9833 is a DDS chip, read about that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesis

If you would clock the AD9833 an ideal **exact** clock then it's output frequency will also be **exactly** what it should be. It follows a certain mathematical relation **exactly** as a DDS is a clocked circuit.

There is no such thing as an ideal **exact** clock, in practice we would use a crystal oscillator which can be quite accurate. How accurate depends on the crystal and if you calibrate it to an exact frequency.

Due to the way a DDS works it cannot make **every** frequency, it can only make certain frequencies and what those are is related to the frequency of the clock you apply at the input.

If you need an exact frequency like 700 Hz for example then you can choose a lower crystal frequency to make the steps such that 700 Hz is possible. What clock frequency you would need for that 700 Hz I don't know, you would have to dive into the workings of a DDS and do the maths.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency registers are 28 bits wide: with a 25 MHz clock rate, resolution of 0.1 Hz can be achieved; with a 1 MHz clock rate, the AD9833 can be tuned to 0.004 Hz resolution.

It appears you are using 25MHz which must be a Xtal source. If not, that’s your err.

Since your errors are both >1000 ppm yet different , it suggests a software error and not the 25MHz Xtal which ought to be   <<50 ppm error and cannot be > 200 ppm error.

Simple solution is use 1MHz XO clock and redo software.

Comment: can you explain to me how did you get my error which is >1000ppm? How to calculate to get such value in parts per million?

Comment: (A-B)/A * 1e6. For A= ideal in [ppm]